# How to add a library for an app which uses lower version of Kotlin without upgrading app's Kotlin plugin's version?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Currently I have an app which uses '1.7.21' version for Kotlin:
`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21"`

It works fine and I can make the build with the latest version of Studio and Android Gradle Plugin.

But I need to add one library which uses a higher version of Kotlin (1.9.0).

When I add it I can't make a build anymore:

> .gradle/caches/transforms-3/9d5ec3680cc0f4f2551fcfbe23e12937/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module:
> Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
> version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

I can't easily update app's version of Kotlin because it still uses `'kotlin-android-extensions'` plugin which doesn't work with the latest versions of Kotlin, so I would need to rewrite a lot of code

Comment: Have you found any solution? I also stucked in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade that library(module) kotlin version to **1.7.21** if you are not using that library through gradle import